# Can anybody tell me what is meaning of 405 not allowed in postman

Tags: postman

```
--AAA
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data


{
    "emailSubject": "Envelope Create - PDF PARTIAL Transform - MM Ind_Agency_Agree",
    "emailBlurb": "PDF PARTICIAL Transform",
    "status": "created",
    "compositeTemplates": 
    [{
            "inlineTemplates": 
            [{
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "recipients": {
                           "signers": 
                           [{
                                    "name": "Principal First And Last Names HERE",
                                    "email": "mittal.soniya3@gmail.com",
                                    "recipientId": "1",
                                    "routingOrder": "1",
                                    "clientUserId":"1234",
                                    "tabs":{
                                         "signHereTabs": [{
                                         "tabLabel":"Principal_eSignSignHere"
                                            }],
                                         "dateSignedTabs": [{
                                            "tabLabel": "FR2050IA_Principal_Date_eSignDateSigned"
                                            }],
                                         "textTabs": [
                                             {
                                               "tabLabel": "Principal1_Name",
                                               "value": "Joe Smith",
                                             }]
                                }

                        }],
                        "carbonCopies": [{
                            "email": "rishumittal.mittal3@gmail.com",
                            "name": "Lumari Vazquez",
                            "recipientId": "3",
                            "routingOrder": "3"
                        }]            
                  }  
            }],
            "document": {
              "name": "IM Agreement Individual-Gavin Moore Fran List TIC IM.pdf",
              "documentId": "1",
              "transformPdfFields": true
            }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Most likely reason would be that you've got postman set to do a GET request instead of a POST.

Answer (score 1):

Meaning of 405 (Method Not Allowed) is that the method received in the request-line is known by the source server but not supported by destination resource.

The origin server MUST generate an Allow header field in a 405 response containing a list of the target resource's currently supported methods.

**Possible Cause that you are getting this in postman:**

1. Method type mismatched Eg. For GET Method sending a request as POST Method or vice versa.
2. Wrong request PATH
3. Service you are trying to hit maybe it's not correctly started and running.